# Proper way to login into facebook from a c++ application?

Tags: c++, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Users can register on my *webpage* using either a new usr/pass or their facebook credentials. But I also have a standalone desktop c++ application. What would be the proper way to let them log-in in the desktop application using facebook credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to embed a web browser to make a request to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token` and listen for the URI to change to get your token.

More on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/